# Using Chrome/Python/Selenium to click button - After porting code to Windows 10 getting error

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I have code that opens a webpage, clicks a button, then logs on with userid/password. I recently moved the code to a Windows 10 laptop and now the code gets the error below. Here is the code:

```
  time.sleep(2)
  inputElement = driver.find_element_by_class_name('hpui-primary-button')
  inputElement.click()
```

Here's the error I get:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element https://cf.passport.hpe.com/hppcf/login.do?cc=US&lang=EN&applandingpage=https://h22204.www2.hpe.com/NEP/Logon/NewHome?hpappid=115940_NONSTOP_PRO_HPE';"> is not clickable at point (710, 300). Other element would receive the click: ...

I tried adding a longer delay, but the page loads fine. Worked on Windows 7, not on Windows 10.

Comment: does it way which element after `Other element would receive the click: ...`?

Comment: add the page source for more details

Comment: @Kiril: It says:    Other element would receive the click: <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-left: 5px;">...</td>

Comment: @nandal: Here's the source of the button:                                                        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
               Sign in using your HPE Passport account 
                <input type="button" class="hpui-primary-button" value="Sign-in with HPE Passport" onclick="window.location = 'https://cf.passport.hpe.com/hppcf/login.do?cc=US&amp;lang=EN&amp;applandingpage=https://h22204.www2.hpe.com/NEP/Logon/NewHome?hpappid=115940_NONSTOP_PRO_HPE';" />
                 <br>
            <br />   
            </td>
        </tr>

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name("hpui-primary-button").click()

Comment: Relevant HTML of the element identified as `find_element_by_class_name('hpui-primary-button')` please

Comment: @bhupathituraga, tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @DebanjanB, html code is in a previous comment to nandal.

Comment: Fixed it. Replaced inputElement.click() with:                                inputElement.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)